# Read a message from a topic in a different subscription than the LogicApp (Azure)

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, subscription

For a project I'm doing a Proof of Concept by reading messages from an azure topic and calling an API in OutSystems. The problem I'm having is that my logic app is in subscription **A** and the topic I'm trying to read from is in Subscription **B**. As you can see in the picture this is the current setup I have. When I'm running the trigger, nothing happens. My educated guess is that it only looks inside the subscription where the logic app resides. Would this be correct? If so, is there a way I can connect to that other subscription somehow? I'm not able to create logicapps in that other subscription unfortunately.

Thanks in advance!

[Current setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NLcAB.png)

I tried finding some information online but wasn't able to find a clear answer.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no direct way to read message from a topic in a different subscription than the Logic App.
To achieve this scenario, you can use service principal. Below are steps you can follow,

- Create app registration in subscription where logic app is created.
- To create app registration,
  Go to Active directory>Click Add>Select App registration
  [image]
- Provide name for app and select account types. Then click on register.
  [image]
- Note down the client id and secret values which can be used in next steps.
- Due to access restrictions can’t proceed further in my case so you can follow below steps.
- Go to the subscription where service bus is created.
- Select the resource group and open Access control.
  [image]
- Select the app created in another subscription and give contributor role and save the role assignment.
  In this way you can read messages from service bus which is in another subscription.